# How to access the errors in TFSBuild 2010

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a CI build configured in TFSBuild 2010 that creates a work item when the build fails. I would like to be able to put the build error messages into the work item description but I can't find any good way of accessing the error information.

Is there anyone who has solved this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the build errors and/or warnings from the BuildInformation property of the IBuildDetail object that represents your build.

Some sample code for doing this can be found in this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2011/02/08/tfs-2010-viewing-the-build-details-log-view-in-visual-studio-is-very-slow.aspx).

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(teamProjectCollectionUrl);
IBuildServer buildServer = collection.GetService<IBuildServer>();
IBuildDetail build = buildServer.GetBuild(buildUri, new String[] { InformationTypes.BuildError, InformationTypes.BuildWarning }, QueryOptions.None);

List<IBuildInformationNode> errorNodes = build.Information.GetNodesByType(InformationTypes.BuildError, false);
```

Comment: I tried this approach but on a failed build I got 0 nodes :-(

Comment: How did you build fail? Can you share the build log somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: I deliberatly removed a semicolon ";" in order to force the build to break with a compiler error.

Comment: Unfortunatly this was deemed of not high enough priority to allow me to spend more time figuring this out :-( but I will mark this answer as correct untill proven otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Duat Le, however, sometimes you have to force a save on the Information Nodes to get the data to show up.

Try this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(teamProjectCollectionUrl);
IBuildServer buildServer = collection.GetService<IBuildServer>();
IBuildDetail build = buildServer.GetBuild(buildUri, new String[] {InformationTypes.BuildError, InformationTypes.BuildWarning }, QueryOptions.None);
build.Information.Save();
List<IBuildInformationNode> errorNodes = build.Information.GetNodesByType(InformationTypes.BuildError, false);
```